# False Error Message in Eclipse for Ant Include Task

Tags: eclipse, ant, include

In my ant build I am including a second ant build file (*build.xml*):

```
<project name="Including" default="echoC" basedir=".">

    <include file="build.xml" as="Included"/>

    <target name="echoC" depends="Included.echoB">
        <echo>C</echo>      
    </target>

</project>
```

*build.xml* is in the same directory as the including build file and everything is working fine actually. I can run the target *echoC* and also the target *echoB* from the included build file is executed first.

What is irritating however is that Eclipse is displaying the error message ***Target Included.echoB does not exist in this project*** in the Ant Editor. Does anybody know how to get rid of that?

Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 3):

This seems a bug in Eclipse according to https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=412809. The comments suggest there is no support for the task in the editor.

Using the `import` task instead works fine.